# How to put double quotes around first 2 numerical elements of each line inside a notepad++ file?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am new to regular expressions.
I have a csv file, which i am editing through Notepad++. Current File(around 10k lines) looks like-

```
    1,1,"Establishes ",5
    2,2,"Establishes",1
    3,3,"Establishes",4
    4,4,"Establishes",2
    5,5,"Establishes",1
.......... and so on..
```

Desired Result, which i would be needing is-

```
    "1","1","Establishes ",5
    "2","2","Establishes",1
    "3","3","Establishes",4
    "4","4","Establishes",2
    "5","5","Establishes",1
```

Comment: Are `1,1` `2,2` ... just placeholders or always digits, and can you show your current regex please? It helps with understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP didn't say how much data they need to edit, I'm adding this answer. It uses the feature of **manually editing columns of text** which is what tipped me over to Notepad++ decades (!) ago.

For anything over a "reasonable amount of manual work", a regex approach like Onur's is the way to go. If you have, say, only a few files of a few thousand lines each to process:

1. Open the file in Notepad++.
2. Select and copy a double quote character.
3. Insert an entire column of double quote characters to the left of the second element by doing the following:

   - Place cursor in first row just to the left of the second element.
     [image]
   - Hold `ALT`+`SHIFT` down, scroll the document to the end, use the mouse to place the cursor in the last row just to the left of the second element, and release the `ALT`+`SHIFT` keys. You'll see a vertical line showing that you've selected the entire column.
     [image]
   - Enter `CTRL`+`V` to paste the double quote character you copied ... and voila!
     [image]
4. Repeat step 3 for the right hand side of the second element and then for the left and right hand side of the first element.

This assumes all the columns of text line up. You can't, for example, do this across rows that have double digit values in the first or second element.

In the ongoing effort to wrangle text, perhaps this will give you another tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

Search pattern:

```
([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^\n]+)
```

Replace pattern:

```
"$1", "$2", $3, $4
```

To learn how to make a regex replacement in notepad++, you can look at the:
https://www.technical-recipes.com/2020/using-regex-to-find-and-replace-text-in-notepad/ ([Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20221014194810/https://www.technical-recipes.com/2020/using-regex-to-find-and-replace-text-in-notepad/))

---

In search pattern:

- `[^,]` => Any character except ","
- `[^,]+` => One or more `[^,]`
- `[^\n]` => Any character except the new line
- `[^\n]+` => One or more `[^\n]`

In replace pattern:

- `$1` => The first matched group